# How to get keyboard name? (to visually distinguish keyboards in a specific language)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, keyboard-layout

I have for example 2 languages installed — English and Russian. And Russian has 2 keyboards — Ordinary and Mnemonic:

[image]

When I run the code:

```
UINT uLayouts;
HKL  *lpList = NULL;
wchar_t szBufLng[512], szBufCtry[512];

uLayouts = GetKeyboardLayoutList(0, NULL);
lpList   = (HKL*)LocalAlloc(LPTR, (uLayouts * sizeof(HKL)));
uLayouts = GetKeyboardLayoutList(uLayouts, lpList);

for(int i = 0; i < uLayouts; ++i)
{
    GetLocaleInfo(MAKELCID(((UINT)lpList[i] & 0xffffffff), 
    SORT_DEFAULT), LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, szBufLng, 512);
    GetLocaleInfo(MAKELCID(((UINT)lpList[i] & 0xffffffff), 
    SORT_DEFAULT), LOCALE_SISO3166CTRYNAME, szBufCtry, 512);
    wprintf(L"%s-%s, %x\n", szBufLng, szBufCtry, (UINT)lpList[i]);
    memset(szBufLng, 0, 512);
    memset(szBufCtry, 0, 512);
}

if(lpList)
    LocalFree(lpList);
```

I get the following result:

```
en-US, 04090409
ru-RU, 04190419
ru-RU, f0330419
```

My question is how to distinguish the mnemonic?
At least to display something like this:

```
en-US,  04090409
ru-RU,  04190419
rum-RU, f0330419
```

How to get keyboard name?

Same problem is discussed here (no solution):
https://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?492287-Keyboard-Layout-Name

http://web.archive.org/web/20081025132249/http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2004/12/05/275231.aspx

http://web.archive.org/web/20100330193933/http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2008/09/29/8968315.aspx

Comment: You might be looking for [`GetKeyboardLayoutName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayoutnamew)

Comment: It can't help me. I need to enumerate all layouts. GetKeyboardLayoutName just retrieves the name of the active keyboard layout.

Comment: You can call `ActivateKeyboardLayout`, then `GetKeyboardLayoutName`

Comment: I've tried GetKeyboardLayoutName. It just returns 00000409 for English layout, 00000419 for ordinary Russian and 00020419 for mnemonic. I also added Russian Azerbaijan keyboard — it returns 0000082C for it.

Comment: The layouts are stored here: \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts\ 
But I don't know how to properly extract them from there.

Comment: Try `LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME2` (`0x00000067`) to get 3-letter language name (it requires Vista or later)

Comment: LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME2 returns "rus" for both (ordinary and mnemonic).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get display name of the current selected keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098366/how-to-get-display-name-of-the-current-selected-keyboard-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I exported data from the registry (\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts) in Windows 10 and based on it created a table. And with the help of SHLoadIndirectString got the localized name of the keyboard.

```
struct LAYOUT_KEYBOARD_INFO {
    LCID layout_id;
    short display_name_id;
    wchar_t default_keyboard_name[64];
};

LAYOUT_KEYBOARD_INFO LAYOUT_KEYBOARDS[] = {
    {0x0401, 5084, L"Arabic (101)"},
    {0x0402, 5053, L"Bulgarian (Typewriter)"},
    {0x0404, 5065, L"Chinese (Traditional) - US Keyboard"},
    {0x0405, 5031, L"Czech"},
    {0x0406, 5007, L"Danish"},
    {0x0407, 5011, L"German"},
    {0x0408, 5046, L"Greek"},
    {0x0409, 5000, L"US"},
    {0x040A, 5020, L"Spanish"},
    {0x040B, 5009, L"Finnish"},
    {0x040C, 5010, L"French"},
    {0x040D, 5083, L"Hebrew"},
    {0x040E, 5033, L"Hungarian"},
    {0x040F, 5013, L"Icelandic"},
    {0x0410, 5015, L"Italian"},
    {0x0411, 5061, L"Japanese"},
    {0x0412, 5063, L"Korean"},
    {0x0413, 5008, L"Dutch"},
    {0x0414, 5018, L"Norwegian"},
    {0x0415, 5035, L"Polish (Programmers)"},
    {0x0416, 5003, L"Portuguese (Brazilian ABNT)"},
    {0x0418, 5037, L"Romanian (Legacy)"},
    {0x0419, 5055, L"Russian"},
    {0x041A, 5030, L"Standard"},
    {0x041B, 5039, L"Slovak"},
    {0x041C, 5029, L"Albanian"},
    {0x041D, 5022, L"Swedish"},
    {0x041E, 5079, L"Thai Kedmanee"},
    {0x041F, 5060, L"Turkish Q"},
    {0x0420, 5129, L"Urdu"},
    {0x0422, 5058, L"Ukrainian"},
    {0x0423, 5052, L"Belarusian"},
    {0x0424, 5041, L"Slovenian"},
    {0x0425, 5042, L"Estonian"},
    {0x0426, 5043, L"Latvian"},
    {0x0427, 5045, L"Lithuanian IBM"},
    {0x0428, 5151, L"Tajik"},
    {0x0429, 5124, L"Persian"},
    {0x042A, 5118, L"Vietnamese"},
    {0x042B, 5120, L"Armenian Eastern"},
    {0x042C, 5117, L"Azeri Latin"},
    {0x042E, 5163, L"Sorbian Standard (Legacy)"},
    {0x042F, 5109, L"Macedonian (FYROM)"},
    {0x0432, 5191, L"Setswana"},
    {0x0437, 5119, L"Georgian"},
    {0x0438, 5108, L"Faeroese"},
    {0x0439, 5096, L"Devanagari - INSCRIPT"},
    {0x043A, 5140, L"Maltese 47-Key"},
    {0x043B, 5138, L"Norwegian with Sami"},
    {0x043F, 5113, L"Kazakh"},
    {0x0440, 5128, L"Kyrgyz Cyrillic"},
    {0x0442, 5150, L"Turkmen"},
    {0x0444, 5116, L"Tatar (Legacy)"},
    {0x0445, 5135, L"Bengali"},
    {0x0446, 5101, L"Punjabi"},
    {0x0447, 5097, L"Gujarati"},
    {0x0448, 5100, L"Oriya"},
    {0x0449, 5102, L"Tamil"},
    {0x044A, 5103, L"Telugu"},
    {0x044B, 5098, L"Kannada"},
    {0x044C, 5139, L"Malayalam"},
    {0x044D, 5177, L"Assamese - INSCRIPT"},
    {0x044E, 5104, L"Marathi"},
    {0x0450, 5127, L"Mongolian Cyrillic"},
    {0x0451, 5154, L"Tibetan (PRC)"},
    {0x0452, 5145, L"United Kingdom Extended"},
    {0x0453, 5161, L"Khmer"},
    {0x0454, 5162, L"Lao"},
    {0x045A, 5130, L"Syriac"},
    {0x045B, 5166, L"Sinhala"},
    {0x045C, 5209, L"Cherokee Nation"},
    {0x0461, 5169, L"Nepali"},
    {0x0463, 5159, L"Pashto (Afghanistan)"},
    {0x0465, 5132, L"Divehi Phonetic"},
    {0x0468, 5187, L"Hausa"},
    {0x046A, 5189, L"Yoruba"},
    {0x046C, 5186, L"Sesotho sa Leboa"},
    {0x046D, 5148, L"Bashkir"},
    {0x046E, 5168, L"Luxembourgish"},
    {0x046F, 5170, L"Greenlandic"},
    {0x0470, 5188, L"Igbo"},
    {0x0474, 5231, L"Guarani"},
    {0x0475, 5198, L"Hawaiian"},
    {0x0480, 5165, L"Uyghur (Legacy)"},
    {0x0481, 5146, L"Maori"},
    {0x0485, 5160, L"Sakha"},
    {0x0488, 5190, L"Wolof"},
    {0x0492, 5199, L"Central Kurdish"},
    {0x0804, 5072, L"Chinese (Simplified) - US Keyboard"},
    {0x0807, 5024, L"Swiss German"},
    {0x0809, 5025, L"United Kingdom"},
    {0x080A, 5017, L"Latin American"},
    {0x080C, 5002, L"Belgian French"},
    {0x0813, 5001, L"Belgian (Period)"},
    {0x0816, 5019, L"Portuguese"},
    {0x081A, 5038, L"Serbian (Latin)"},
    {0x082C, 5115, L"Azeri Cyrillic"},
    {0x083B, 5144, L"Swedish with Sami"},
    {0x0843, 5114, L"Uzbek Cyrillic"},
    {0x0850, 5158, L"Mongolian (Mongolian Script)"},
    {0x085D, 5156, L"Inuktitut - Latin"},
    {0x085F, 5229, L"Central Atlas Tamazight"},
    {0x0C04, 5192, L"Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong S.A.R.) - US Keyboard"},
    {0x0C0C, 5005, L"Canadian French (Legacy)"},
    {0x0C1A, 5057, L"Serbian (Cyrillic)"},
    {0x0C51, 5235, L"Dzongkha"},
    {0x1004, 5193, L"Chinese (Simplified, Singapore) - US Keyboard"},
    {0x1009, 5004, L"Canadian French"},
    {0x100C, 5023, L"Swiss French"},
    {0x105F, 5207, L"Tifinagh (Basic)"},
    {0x1404, 5194, L"Chinese (Traditional, Macao S.A.R.) - US Keyboard"},
    {0x1809, 5014, L"Irish"},
    {0x201A, 5155, L"Bosnian (Cyrillic)"},
    {0x4009, 5196, L"India"},
// Added F to "Layout Id"
    {0xF028, 5085, L"Arabic (102)"},
    {0xF004, 5054, L"Bulgarian (Latin)"},
    {0xF005, 5032, L"Czech (QWERTY)"},
    {0xF012, 5012, L"German (IBM)"},
    {0xF016, 5048, L"Greek (220)"},
    {0xF002, 5092, L"United States-Dvorak"},
    {0xF086, 5021, L"Spanish Variation"},
    {0xF006, 5034, L"Hungarian 101-key"},
    {0xF003, 5016, L"Italian (142)"},
    {0xF007, 5036, L"Polish (214)"},
    {0xF010, 5126, L"Portuguese (Brazilian ABNT2)"},
    {0xF0A5, 5175, L"Romanian (Standard)"},
    {0xF008, 5056, L"Russian (Typewriter)"},
    {0xF013, 5040, L"Slovak (QWERTY)"},
    {0xF021, 5080, L"Thai Pattachote"},
    {0xF014, 5059, L"Turkish F"},
    {0xF015, 5044, L"Latvian (QWERTY)"},
    {0xF027, 5088, L"Lithuanian"},
    {0xF025, 5121, L"Armenian Western"},
    {0xF0BD, 5234, L"Azerbaijani (Standard)"},
    {0xF09F, 5164, L"Sorbian Extended"},
    {0xF0A4, 5174, L"Macedonian (FYROM) - Standard"},
    {0xF0AB, 5182, L"Georgian (QWERTY)"},
    {0xF00C, 5105, L"Hindi Traditional"},
    {0xF02B, 5141, L"Maltese 48-Key"},
    {0xF02C, 5143, L"Sami Extended Norway"},
    {0xF0BC, 5233, L"Tatar"},
    {0xF02A, 5136, L"Bengali - INSCRIPT (Legacy)"},
    {0xF0B5, 5222, L"Tibetan (PRC) - Updated"},
    {0xF02F, 5200, L"Khmer (NIDA)"},
    {0xF00E, 5131, L"Syriac Phonetic"},
    {0xF0A0, 5167, L"Sinhala - Wij 9"},
    {0xF037, 5201, L"Cherokee Nation Phonetic"},
    {0xF0A7, 5171, L"Inuktitut - Naqittaut"},
    {0xF00D, 5133, L"Divehi Typewriter"},
    {0xF0AD, 5185, L"Uyghur"},
    {0xF01E, 5089, L"Belgian (Comma)"},
    {0xF02D, 5137, L"Finnish with Sami"},
    {0xF0B2, 5225, L"Traditional Mongolian (Standard)"},
    {0xF030, 5249, L"Myanmar (Phonetic order)"},
    {0xF020, 5110, L"Canadian Multilingual Standard"},
    {0xF036, 5208, L"Tifinagh (Full)"},
    {0xF026, 5125, L"Gaelic"},
    {0xF029, 5086, L"Arabic (102) AZERTY"},
    {0xF0A3, 5173, L"Bulgarian (Phonetic)"},
    {0xF00A, 5087, L"Czech Programmers"},
    {0xF018, 5049, L"Greek (319)"},
    {0xF001, 5026, L"United States-International"},
    {0xF03D, 5214, L"Hebrew (Standard)"},
    {0xF0A6, 5176, L"Romanian (Programmers)"},
    {0xF033, 5203, L"Russian - Mnemonic"},
    {0xF022, 5081, L"Thai Kedmanee (non-ShiftLock)"},
    {0xF0A8, 5179, L"Ukrainian (Enhanced)"},
    {0xF0B1, 5224, L"Latvian (Standard)"},
    {0xF0A1, 5172, L"Lithuanian Standard"},
    {0xF038, 5217, L"Armenian Phonetic"},
    {0xF0AE, 5184, L"Sorbian Standard"},
    {0xF0AC, 5181, L"Georgian (Ergonomic)"},
    {0xF0A9, 5178, L"Bengali - INSCRIPT"},
    {0xF0C8, 5246, L"Tamil 99"},
    {0xF02E, 5142, L"Sami Extended Finland-Sweden"},
    {0xF031, 5204, L"New Tai Lue"},
    {0xF0AA, 5180, L"Bulgarian"},
    {0xF017, 5050, L"Greek (220) Latin"},
    {0xF01A, 5027, L"United States-Dvorak for left hand"},
    {0xF023, 5082, L"Thai Pattachote (non-ShiftLock)"},
    {0xF039, 5218, L"Armenian Typewriter"},
    {0xF03B, 5215, L"Georgian Ministry of Education and Science Schools"},
    {0xF034, 5205, L"Tai Le"},
    {0xF0AF, 5195, L"Bulgarian (Phonetic Traditional)"},
    {0xF011, 5051, L"Greek (319) Latin"},
    {0xF01B, 5028, L"United States-Dvorak for right hand"},
    {0xF03C, 5216, L"Georgian (Old Alphabets)"},
    {0xF032, 5206, L"Ogham"},
    {0xF019, 5047, L"Greek Latin"},
    {0xF00B, 5123, L"US English Table for IBM Arabic 238_L"},
    {0xF03A, 5213, L"Persian (Standard)"},
    {0xF01F, 5122, L"Greek Polytonic"},
    {0xF03E, 5210, L"Lisu (Basic)"},
    {0xF03F, 5211, L"Lisu (Standard)"},
    {0xF040, 5212, L"N’Ko"},
    {0xF041, 5219, L"Phags-pa"},
    {0xF0B3, 5220, L"Buginese"},
    {0xF0B4, 5221, L"Gothic"},
    {0xF0B6, 5223, L"Ol Chiki"},
    {0xF0B7, 5226, L"Osmanya"},
    {0xF0B8, 5227, L"Old Italic"},
    {0xF0B9, 5228, L"Sora"},
    {0xF0BA, 5230, L"Javanese"},
    {0xF0BB, 5232, L"Futhark"},
    {0xF0CB, 5250, L"Myanmar (Visual Order)"},
    {0xF0CC, 5251, L"ADLaM"},
    {0xF0CD, 5252, L"Osage"}
};

CString GetLayoutKeyboardDisplayName(DWORD layout, bool fLocalized = true) {
    DWORD layout_id = layout >> 16;
    CString keyboard_name = L"";    
    int number_of_elements = sizeof(LAYOUT_KEYBOARDS)/sizeof(LAYOUT_KEYBOARDS[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++)
        if (LAYOUT_KEYBOARDS[i].layout_id == layout_id) {
            wchar_t szBuf[512];
            if (fLocalized && SHLoadIndirectString(L"@%SystemRoot%\\system32\\input.dll,-" + IntToStr(LAYOUT_KEYBOARDS[i].display_name_id), szBuf, 512, NULL) == S_OK)
                keyboard_name.Format(L"%s", szBuf);
            else
                keyboard_name = LAYOUT_KEYBOARDS[i].default_keyboard_name;
            memset(szBuf, 0, 512);
            return keyboard_name;
        }

    keyboard_name.Format(L"%X", layout_id);
    keyboard_name.TrimLeft(L"0");
    return keyboard_name;
}    
//...
wprintf(L"%X, %s\n", (UINT)lpList[i], GetLayoutKeyboardDisplayName((UINT)lpList[i]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard layouts can be obtained from windows regedit.
the following is python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# 从注册表中获取所有的键盘布局
# get all keyboard layouts from win regedit
import json
import winreg


def get_keyboard_layouts():
    """
    windows 从注册表中获取所有的键盘布局
    参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66841378
    """
    print('get keyboard layouts')

    # reg root path
    loc_root = winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

    # Keyboard Layouts reg path
    loc_keyboards = r'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts'

    # open reg path, get handle
    handle_keyboards = winreg.OpenKey(key=loc_root, sub_key=loc_keyboards)

    # get info of reg 'Keyboard Layouts'
    # The result is a tuple of 3 items:
    # An integer that identifies the number of sub keys this key has.
    # An integer that identifies the number of values this key has.
    # An integer that identifies when the key was last modified (if available)
    # as 100's of nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1600.
    info_keyboards = winreg.QueryInfoKey(handle_keyboards)

    # get sub key length
    keyboards_len = info_keyboards[0]

    keyboard_layout = {}

    # traverse to get sub key
    for i in range(keyboards_len):
        # sub key name
        name_keyboard = winreg.EnumKey(handle_keyboards, i)

        # sub key path
        loc_keyboard = fr'{loc_keyboards}\{name_keyboard}'

        # open sub key
        handle_keyboard = winreg.OpenKey(key=loc_root, sub_key=loc_keyboard)

        # get layout text
        layout_text = winreg.QueryValueEx(handle_keyboard, 'Layout Text')[0]

        # save layout name and layout text
        keyboard_layout[name_keyboard] = layout_text

        # 转换关系参考 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047253/
        # to hex string
        # {'00000401': 'Arabic (101)', '00000402': 'Bulgarian (Typewriter)'}
        # 得到的是 16 进制的字符串, 要转换为 0x804 的 16进制数
        # 16 进制字符串转 16 进制整数
        # int(win32api.GetKeyboardLayoutName(), 10) > 804
        # 16 进制字符串转 10 进制整数
        # int(win32api.GetKeyboardLayoutName(), 16) > 2052
        name_keyboard_hex = hex(int(name_keyboard, 16))
        # save hex layout name and layout text
        keyboard_layout[name_keyboard_hex] = layout_text

        handle_keyboard.Close()

    handle_keyboards.Close()

    return keyboard_layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(json.dumps(get_keyboard_layouts()))

keyboard_layouts = {
    "00000401": "Arabic (101)",
    "0x401": "Arabic (101)",
    "00000402": "Bulgarian (Typewriter)",
    "0x402": "Bulgarian (Typewriter)",
    "00000404": "Chinese (Traditional) - US Keyboard",
    "0x404": "Chinese (Traditional) - US Keyboard",
    "00000405": "Czech",
    "0x405": "Czech",
    "00000406": "Danish",
    "0x406": "Danish",
    "00000407": "German",
    "0x407": "German",
    "00000408": "Greek",
    "0x408": "Greek",
    "00000409": "US",
    "0x409": "US",
    "0000040a": "Spanish",
    "0x40a": "Spanish",
    "0000040b": "Finnish",
    "0x40b": "Finnish",
    "0000040c": "French",
    "0x40c": "French",
    "0000040d": "Hebrew",
    "0x40d": "Hebrew",
    "0000040e": "Hungarian",
    "0x40e": "Hungarian",
    "0000040f": "Icelandic",
    "0x40f": "Icelandic",
    "00000410": "Italian",
    "0x410": "Italian",
    "00000411": "Japanese",
    "0x411": "Japanese",
    "00000412": "Korean",
    "0x412": "Korean",
    "00000413": "Dutch",
    "0x413": "Dutch",
    "00000414": "Norwegian",
    "0x414": "Norwegian",
    "00000415": "Polish (Programmers)",
    "0x415": "Polish (Programmers)",
    "00000416": "Portuguese (Brazilian ABNT)",
    "0x416": "Portuguese (Brazilian ABNT)",
    "00000418": "Romanian (Legacy)",
    "0x418": "Romanian (Legacy)",
    "00000419": "Russian",
    "0x419": "Russian",
    "0000041a": "Standard",
    "0x41a": "Standard",
    "0000041b": "Slovak",
    "0x41b": "Slovak",
    "0000041c": "Albanian",
    "0x41c": "Albanian",
    "0000041d": "Swedish",
    "0x41d": "Swedish",
    "0000041e": "Thai Kedmanee",
    "0x41e": "Thai Kedmanee",
    "0000041f": "Turkish Q",
    "0x41f": "Turkish Q",
    "00000420": "Urdu",
    "0x420": "Urdu",
    "00000422": "Ukrainian",
    "0x422": "Ukrainian",
    "00000423": "Belarusian",
    "0x423": "Belarusian",
    "00000424": "Slovenian",
    "0x424": "Slovenian",
    "00000425": "Estonian",
    "0x425": "Estonian",
    "00000426": "Latvian",
    "0x426": "Latvian",
    "00000427": "Lithuanian IBM",
    "0x427": "Lithuanian IBM",
    "00000428": "Tajik",
    "0x428": "Tajik",
    "00000429": "Persian",
    "0x429": "Persian",
    "0000042a": "Vietnamese",
    "0x42a": "Vietnamese",
    "0000042b": "Armenian Eastern",
    "0x42b": "Armenian Eastern",
    "0000042c": "Azeri Latin",
    "0x42c": "Azeri Latin",
    "0000042e": "Sorbian Standard (Legacy)",
    "0x42e": "Sorbian Standard (Legacy)",
    "0000042f": "Macedonian (FYROM)",
    "0x42f": "Macedonian (FYROM)",
    "00000432": "Setswana",
    "0x432": "Setswana",
    "00000437": "Georgian",
    "0x437": "Georgian",
    "00000438": "Faeroese",
    "0x438": "Faeroese",
    "00000439": "Devanagari - INSCRIPT",
    "0x439": "Devanagari - INSCRIPT",
    "0000043a": "Maltese 47-Key",
    "0x43a": "Maltese 47-Key",
    "0000043b": "Norwegian with Sami",
    "0x43b": "Norwegian with Sami",
    "0000043f": "Kazakh",
    "0x43f": "Kazakh",
    "00000440": "Kyrgyz Cyrillic",
    "0x440": "Kyrgyz Cyrillic",
    "00000442": "Turkmen",
    "0x442": "Turkmen",
    "00000444": "Tatar (Legacy)",
    "0x444": "Tatar (Legacy)",
    "00000445": "Bengali",
    "0x445": "Bengali",
    "00000446": "Punjabi",
    "0x446": "Punjabi",
    "00000447": "Gujarati",
    "0x447": "Gujarati",
    "00000448": "Oriya",
    "0x448": "Oriya",
    "00000449": "Tamil",
    "0x449": "Tamil",
    "0000044a": "Telugu",
    "0x44a": "Telugu",
    "0000044b": "Kannada",
    "0x44b": "Kannada",
    "0000044c": "Malayalam",
    "0x44c": "Malayalam",
    "0000044d": "Assamese - INSCRIPT",
    "0x44d": "Assamese - INSCRIPT",
    "0000044e": "Marathi",
    "0x44e": "Marathi",
    "00000450": "Mongolian Cyrillic",
    "0x450": "Mongolian Cyrillic",
    "00000451": "Tibetan (PRC)",
    "0x451": "Tibetan (PRC)",
    "00000452": "United Kingdom Extended",
    "0x452": "United Kingdom Extended",
    "00000453": "Khmer",
    "0x453": "Khmer",
    "00000454": "Lao",
    "0x454": "Lao",
    "0000045a": "Syriac",
    "0x45a": "Syriac",
    "0000045b": "Sinhala",
    "0x45b": "Sinhala",
    "0000045c": "Cherokee Nation",
    "0x45c": "Cherokee Nation",
    "00000461": "Nepali",
    "0x461": "Nepali",
    "00000463": "Pashto (Afghanistan)",
    "0x463": "Pashto (Afghanistan)",
    "00000465": "Divehi Phonetic",
    "0x465": "Divehi Phonetic",
    "00000468": "Hausa",
    "0x468": "Hausa",
    "0000046a": "Yoruba",
    "0x46a": "Yoruba",
    "0000046c": "Sesotho sa Leboa",
    "0x46c": "Sesotho sa Leboa",
    "0000046d": "Bashkir",
    "0x46d": "Bashkir",
    "0000046e": "Luxembourgish",
    "0x46e": "Luxembourgish",
    "0000046f": "Greenlandic",
    "0x46f": "Greenlandic",
    "00000470": "Igbo",
    "0x470": "Igbo",
    "00000474": "Guarani",
    "0x474": "Guarani",
    "00000475": "Hawaiian",
    "0x475": "Hawaiian",
    "00000480": "Uyghur (Legacy)",
    "0x480": "Uyghur (Legacy)",
    "00000481": "Maori",
    "0x481": "Maori",
    "00000485": "Sakha",
    "0x485": "Sakha",
    "00000488": "Wolof",
    "0x488": "Wolof",
    "00000492": "Central Kurdish",
    "0x492": "Central Kurdish",
    "00000804": "Chinese (Simplified) - US Keyboard",
    "0x804": "Chinese (Simplified) - US Keyboard",
    "00000807": "Swiss German",
    "0x807": "Swiss German",
    "00000809": "United Kingdom",
    "0x809": "United Kingdom",
    "0000080a": "Latin American",
    "0x80a": "Latin American",
    "0000080c": "Belgian French",
    "0x80c": "Belgian French",
    "00000813": "Belgian (Period)",
    "0x813": "Belgian (Period)",
    "00000816": "Portuguese",
    "0x816": "Portuguese",
    "0000081a": "Serbian (Latin)",
    "0x81a": "Serbian (Latin)",
    "0000082c": "Azeri Cyrillic",
    "0x82c": "Azeri Cyrillic",
    "0000083b": "Swedish with Sami",
    "0x83b": "Swedish with Sami",
    "00000843": "Uzbek Cyrillic",
    "0x843": "Uzbek Cyrillic",
    "00000850": "Mongolian (Mongolian Script)",
    "0x850": "Mongolian (Mongolian Script)",
    "0000085d": "Inuktitut - Latin",
    "0x85d": "Inuktitut - Latin",
    "0000085f": "Central Atlas Tamazight",
    "0x85f": "Central Atlas Tamazight",
    "00000c04": "Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong S.A.R.) - US Keyboard",
    "0xc04": "Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong S.A.R.) - US Keyboard",
    "00000c0c": "Canadian French (Legacy)",
    "0xc0c": "Canadian French (Legacy)",
    "00000c1a": "Serbian (Cyrillic)",
    "0xc1a": "Serbian (Cyrillic)",
    "00000C51": "Dzongkha",
    "0xc51": "Dzongkha",
    "00001004": "Chinese (Simplified, Singapore) - US Keyboard",
    "0x1004": "Chinese (Simplified, Singapore) - US Keyboard",
    "00001009": "Canadian French",
    "0x1009": "Canadian French",
    "0000100c": "Swiss French",
    "0x100c": "Swiss French",
    "0000105f": "Tifinagh (Basic)",
    "0x105f": "Tifinagh (Basic)",
    "00001404": "Chinese (Traditional, Macao S.A.R.) - US Keyboard",
    "0x1404": "Chinese (Traditional, Macao S.A.R.) - US Keyboard",
    "00001809": "Irish",
    "0x1809": "Irish",
    "0000201a": "Bosnian (Cyrillic)",
    "0x201a": "Bosnian (Cyrillic)",
    "00004009": "India",
    "0x4009": "India",
    "00010401": "Arabic (102)",
    "0x10401": "Arabic (102)",
    "00010402": "Bulgarian (Latin)",
    "0x10402": "Bulgarian (Latin)",
    "00010405": "Czech (QWERTY)",
    "0x10405": "Czech (QWERTY)",
    "00010407": "German (IBM)",
    "0x10407": "German (IBM)",
    "00010408": "Greek (220)",
    "0x10408": "Greek (220)",
    "00010409": "United States-Dvorak",
    "0x10409": "United States-Dvorak",
    "0001040a": "Spanish Variation",
    "0x1040a": "Spanish Variation",
    "0001040e": "Hungarian 101-key",
    "0x1040e": "Hungarian 101-key",
    "00010410": "Italian (142)",
    "0x10410": "Italian (142)",
    "00010415": "Polish (214)",
    "0x10415": "Polish (214)",
    "00010416": "Portuguese (Brazilian ABNT2)",
    "0x10416": "Portuguese (Brazilian ABNT2)",
    "00010418": "Romanian (Standard)",
    "0x10418": "Romanian (Standard)",
    "00010419": "Russian (Typewriter)",
    "0x10419": "Russian (Typewriter)",
    "0001041b": "Slovak (QWERTY)",
    "0x1041b": "Slovak (QWERTY)",
    "0001041e": "Thai Pattachote",
    "0x1041e": "Thai Pattachote",
    "0001041f": "Turkish F",
    "0x1041f": "Turkish F",
    "00010426": "Latvian (QWERTY)",
    "0x10426": "Latvian (QWERTY)",
    "00010427": "Lithuanian",
    "0x10427": "Lithuanian",
    "0001042b": "Armenian Western",
    "0x1042b": "Armenian Western",
    "0001042c": "Azerbaijani (Standard)",
    "0x1042c": "Azerbaijani (Standard)",
    "0001042e": "Sorbian Extended",
    "0x1042e": "Sorbian Extended",
    "0001042f": "Macedonian (FYROM) - Standard",
    "0x1042f": "Macedonian (FYROM) - Standard",
    "00010437": "Georgian (QWERTY)",
    "0x10437": "Georgian (QWERTY)",
    "00010439": "Hindi Traditional",
    "0x10439": "Hindi Traditional",
    "0001043a": "Maltese 48-Key",
    "0x1043a": "Maltese 48-Key",
    "0001043b": "Sami Extended Norway",
    "0x1043b": "Sami Extended Norway",
    "00010444": "Tatar",
    "0x10444": "Tatar",
    "00010445": "Bengali - INSCRIPT (Legacy)",
    "0x10445": "Bengali - INSCRIPT (Legacy)",
    "00010451": "Tibetan (PRC) - Updated",
    "0x10451": "Tibetan (PRC) - Updated",
    "00010453": "Khmer (NIDA)",
    "0x10453": "Khmer (NIDA)",
    "0001045a": "Syriac Phonetic",
    "0x1045a": "Syriac Phonetic",
    "0001045b": "Sinhala - Wij 9",
    "0x1045b": "Sinhala - Wij 9",
    "0001045c": "Cherokee Nation Phonetic",
    "0x1045c": "Cherokee Nation Phonetic",
    "0001045d": "Inuktitut - Naqittaut",
    "0x1045d": "Inuktitut - Naqittaut",
    "00010465": "Divehi Typewriter",
    "0x10465": "Divehi Typewriter",
    "00010480": "Uyghur",
    "0x10480": "Uyghur",
    "0001080c": "Belgian (Comma)",
    "0x1080c": "Belgian (Comma)",
    "0001083b": "Finnish with Sami",
    "0x1083b": "Finnish with Sami",
    "00010850": "Traditional Mongolian (Standard)",
    "0x10850": "Traditional Mongolian (Standard)",
    "00010c00": "Myanmar (Phonetic order)",
    "0x10c00": "Myanmar (Phonetic order)",
    "00011009": "Canadian Multilingual Standard",
    "0x11009": "Canadian Multilingual Standard",
    "0001105f": "Tifinagh (Full)",
    "0x1105f": "Tifinagh (Full)",
    "00011809": "Gaelic",
    "0x11809": "Gaelic",
    "00020401": "Arabic (102) AZERTY",
    "0x20401": "Arabic (102) AZERTY",
    "00020402": "Bulgarian (Phonetic)",
    "0x20402": "Bulgarian (Phonetic)",
    "00020405": "Czech Programmers",
    "0x20405": "Czech Programmers",
    "00020408": "Greek (319)",
    "0x20408": "Greek (319)",
    "00020409": "United States-International",
    "0x20409": "United States-International",
    "0002040d": "Hebrew (Standard)",
    "0x2040d": "Hebrew (Standard)",
    "00020418": "Romanian (Programmers)",
    "0x20418": "Romanian (Programmers)",
    "00020419": "Russian - Mnemonic",
    "0x20419": "Russian - Mnemonic",
    "0002041e": "Thai Kedmanee (non-ShiftLock)",
    "0x2041e": "Thai Kedmanee (non-ShiftLock)",
    "00020422": "Ukrainian (Enhanced)",
    "0x20422": "Ukrainian (Enhanced)",
    "00020426": "Latvian (Standard)",
    "0x20426": "Latvian (Standard)",
    "00020427": "Lithuanian Standard",
    "0x20427": "Lithuanian Standard",
    "0002042b": "Armenian Phonetic",
    "0x2042b": "Armenian Phonetic",
    "0002042e": "Sorbian Standard",
    "0x2042e": "Sorbian Standard",
    "00020437": "Georgian (Ergonomic)",
    "0x20437": "Georgian (Ergonomic)",
    "00020445": "Bengali - INSCRIPT",
    "0x20445": "Bengali - INSCRIPT",
    "00020449": "Tamil 99",
    "0x20449": "Tamil 99",
    "0002083b": "Sami Extended Finland-Sweden",
    "0x2083b": "Sami Extended Finland-Sweden",
    "00020c00": "New Tai Lue",
    "0x20c00": "New Tai Lue",
    "00030402": "Bulgarian",
    "0x30402": "Bulgarian",
    "00030408": "Greek (220) Latin",
    "0x30408": "Greek (220) Latin",
    "00030409": "United States-Dvorak for left hand",
    "0x30409": "United States-Dvorak for left hand",
    "0003041e": "Thai Pattachote (non-ShiftLock)",
    "0x3041e": "Thai Pattachote (non-ShiftLock)",
    "0003042b": "Armenian Typewriter",
    "0x3042b": "Armenian Typewriter",
    "00030437": "Georgian Ministry of Education and Science Schools",
    "0x30437": "Georgian Ministry of Education and Science Schools",
    "00030c00": "Tai Le",
    "0x30c00": "Tai Le",
    "00040402": "Bulgarian (Phonetic Traditional)",
    "0x40402": "Bulgarian (Phonetic Traditional)",
    "00040408": "Greek (319) Latin",
    "0x40408": "Greek (319) Latin",
    "00040409": "United States-Dvorak for right hand",
    "0x40409": "United States-Dvorak for right hand",
    "00040437": "Georgian (Old Alphabets)",
    "0x40437": "Georgian (Old Alphabets)",
    "00040c00": "Ogham",
    "0x40c00": "Ogham",
    "00050408": "Greek Latin",
    "0x50408": "Greek Latin",
    "00050409": "US English Table for IBM Arabic 238_L",
    "0x50409": "US English Table for IBM Arabic 238_L",
    "00050429": "Persian (Standard)",
    "0x50429": "Persian (Standard)",
    "00060408": "Greek Polytonic",
    "0x60408": "Greek Polytonic",
    "00070c00": "Lisu (Basic)",
    "0x70c00": "Lisu (Basic)",
    "00080c00": "Lisu (Standard)",
    "0x80c00": "Lisu (Standard)",
    "00090c00": "N\u2019Ko",
    "0x90c00": "N\u2019Ko",
    "000a0c00": "Phags-pa",
    "0xa0c00": "Phags-pa",
    "000b0c00": "Buginese",
    "0xb0c00": "Buginese",
    "000c0c00": "Gothic",
    "0xc0c00": "Gothic",
    "000d0c00": "Ol Chiki",
    "0xd0c00": "Ol Chiki",
    "000e0c00": "Osmanya",
    "0xe0c00": "Osmanya",
    "000f0c00": "Old Italic",
    "0xf0c00": "Old Italic",
    "00100c00": "Sora",
    "0x100c00": "Sora",
    "00110c00": "Javanese",
    "0x110c00": "Javanese",
    "00120c00": "Futhark",
    "0x120c00": "Futhark",
    "00130c00": "Myanmar (Visual Order)",
    "0x130c00": "Myanmar (Visual Order)",
    "00140c00": "ADLaM",
    "0x140c00": "ADLaM",
    "00150c00": "Osage",
    "0x150c00": "Osage"
}
```